# 1C 8.3 (управляемое). Как изменить цвет товара в табличном списке документа, при изменении количества?

Tags: 1с

Как сделать так, чтобы если из списка у одного из ранее добавленного товара увеличивать количество,
то у него изменялся цвет (т.е. в этой строке у товара будет другой цвет)?

Например, если в строке №2 изменим количество (столбец Количество), то цвет шрифта должен быть красным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красный цвет устанавливается так: `СтрокаТЧ.ЦветТекста=Новый Цвет(255,0,0);`

Важно! Этот цвет должен сохраняться, пока не проведем документ. До проведения всегда должен быть красным.

Процедуры:

1. Процедура ТоварыПриПолученииДанных(Элемент, ОформленияСтрок)

Цвета состояния здесь:

Если (СсылкаСостояние = Справочники.ВидыСостоянийЗаказНарядов.Выполнен ИЛИ СсылкаСостояние = Справочники.ВидыСостоянийЗаказНарядов.Закрыт) Тогда

```
        СтрокаТЧ.ЦветТекста=Новый Цвет(128,128,128);
    ИначеЕсли ОсталосьПереместить=0 Тогда
        
        СтрокаТЧ.ЦветТекста=Новый Цвет(128,128,128);
    ИначеЕсли ОсталосьПереместить<=ВозможноПереместить Тогда
        Если Зарезервировано>=ОсталосьПереместить Тогда
            
            СтрокаТЧ.ЦветТекста=Новый Цвет(160,120,200);
        Иначе
            СтрокаТЧ.ЦветТекста=Новый Цвет(0,128,0);
        КонецЕсли;
        Заказано            = СтрокаРезультата.Заказано;
        Зарезервировано     = СтрокаРезультата.Зарезервировано;
        ВПроизводстве       = СтрокаРезультата.ВПроизводстве;
        ОсталосьПереместить = СтрокаРезультата.ОсталосьПереместить;
        ВозможноПереместить = СтрокаРезультата.ВозможноПереместить;
    ИначеЕсли ОсталосьПереместить<=(Заказано+ВозможноПереместить) Тогда
        
        СтрокаТЧ.ЦветТекста=Новый Цвет(128,128,0);
    Иначе
        
        СтрокаТЧ.ЦветТекста=Новый Цвет(0,0,128);
    КонецЕсли;
```

2. Процедура срабатывания после редактирования строки:

   Процедура ТоварыПриОкончанииРедактирования(Элемент, НоваяСтрока, ОтменаРедактирования) Экспорт

   ```
    Если ЭлементыФормы.КоманднаяПанельТовары.Кнопки.Подсветка.Пометка ИЛИ 
        Элемент.Колонки.ОстатокВПроизводстве.Видимость ИЛИ 
        Элемент.Колонки.Заказано.Видимость ИЛИ Элемент.Колонки.ВРезерве.Видимость Тогда

        ТекущаяСтрока = ЭлементыФормы.Товары.ТекущаяСтрока;
        Если НЕ ТекущаяСтрока = Неопределено Тогда
            СтруктураОтбора = Новый Структура;
            СтруктураОтбора.Вставить("Номенклатура", ТекущаяСтрока.Номенклатура);
            СтруктураОтбора.Вставить("ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры", ТекущаяСтрока.ХарактеристикаНоменклатуры);
            ПересчитатьКеш(, СтруктураОтбора);
        КонецЕсли;
    КонецЕсли;

    КонтрольКоличестваДеталейВПроизводстве(ЭтаФорма);
    дкТоварыПриОкончанииРедактирования(ЭтаФорма,Элемент, НоваяСтрока, ОтменаРедактирования);
   ```

   КонецПроцедуры

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы узнать значение реквизита документа/табличной части документа (до изменения пользователя); Следует сделать запрос к базе данных; В запросе указываем *ИмяДокумента* . *ИмяТабличнойЧасти* как они заданы в конфигураторе !

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос("
|ВЫБРАТЬ
|   // Док.Ссылка КАК Ссылка,
|   // Док.НомерСтроки КАК НомерСтроки,
|   Док.Количество КАК Количество
|ИЗ
|   Документ.*ИмяДокумента*.*ИмяТабличнойЧасти* КАК Док
|ГДЕ
|   Док.Ссылка = &Ссылка И
|   Док.НомерСтроки = &НомерСтроки");

Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Ссылка", Ссылка)
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("НомерСтроки", ТекущаяСтрока.НомерСтроки); 

Результат = Запрос.Выполнить(); 
Выборка = Результат.Выбрать(); 

_Количество = Неопределено;  // Количество в документе
Если Выборка.Следующий() Тогда 
    _Количество = Выборка.Количество; 
КонецЕсли;
```